# Making a clone'd thread pthread compatible

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, glibc

I am programming in C on Linux x86-64. I'm using a library which creates a number of threads via a raw `clone` system call rather than using `pthread_create`. These threads run low-level code internal to the library.

I would like to hook one of these threads to introspect its behavior. Hooking the code is easy enough, but I've discovered that I can't call almost anything in libc because the thread state is not configured. `pthread_create` normally inserts a bunch of data into the thread-local storage area indexed by `fs:`. Some of that data, for example, is essential to `libc`'s function, such as the function pointer encryption key (`pointer_guard`) and locale pointer.

So my question is: can I upgrade a `clone`'d thread to a full `pthread` via any mechanism? If not, is there any way that I can call C functions from a `clone`'d thread (such as `printf`, `toupper`, etc. which require libc's thread-local data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some of that data, for example, is essential to libc's function, such as the function pointer encryption key (pointer_guard) and locale pointer.

Correct. Don't forget about `errno`, which is also in there.

> can I upgrade a clone'd thread to a full pthread via any mechanism?

No.

> is there any way that I can call C functions from a clone'd thread

No.

If you have sources to the library, it should be relatively easy to replace direct `clone` calls with `pthread_create`.

If you do not, but the library is available in archive form, you may be able to use `obcopy --rename-symbol` to redirect its `clone` calls to a replacement (e.g. `my_clone`), which can then create a new thread via `pthread_create` and invoke the target function in that thread. Whether this will succeed greatly depends on how much the library cares about details of the `clone`.

It's also probably not worth the trouble.

---

A better alternative may be to implement the introspection *without* calling into libc. Since your `printf` and `toupper` probably only need to deal with `ASCII` and `C` locale, it's not hard to implement limited versions of these functions and use direct system calls to write the output.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered just replacing `clone` in the library, that's a good direction to try. However, in at least one case, it seems like it's possible that it could call `clone` *from a signal handler* (I have not proven this fact yet). I don't think `pthread_create` is async-signal-safe. Maybe I could try and avoid that case, hmm...

I also assume that by "direct system calls" I'll also need to avoid glibc's wrappers, because they might touch the `errno` in TLS, right? Annoying, but I guess this is what I get for using this foot gun of a library...

Comment: Replacing clone() by pthread_create() is not an option as pthread_create() is a call to clone() with those flags : CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID. GLIBC prepares the environment to make some of those flags work as expected and additional parameters are passed to clone() for flags like CLONE_SETTLS, CLONE_PARENT_SETTID... So, if the original call to clone() does not use those flags, the program will result in a different behavior.